# Traefik doesn't create the Let's Encrypt certificate for Service Fabric

Tags: traefik

I had deployed [Traefik](https://github.com/jjcollinge/traefik-on-service-fabric) using Visual Studio, it's successfully getting deployed and creating a certificate and storing it in a key vault. But this certificate is not provided by Let's Encrypt, I can't see issuer as Let's Encrypt Authority.

[image]

The issuer in my certificate is the URL of the Service fabric cluster, and I think it's a Microsoft who's providing that certificate to me.

As mentioned for Let's Encrypt, it provides certificates with 3 months of validity, but the certificate that I got has 1 year of validity to expire.

As explained [here](https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/acme/), I have added everything to the traefik.toml file.

```
    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
      entryPoint = "https"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
  [entryPoints.https.tls]

[retry]

[acme]
  email = "user@domain.com"
  storage = "acme.json"
  entryPoint = "https"
  OnHostRule = true

[acme.httpChallenge]
  entryPoint = "http"
```

Can anybody tell me what I'm missing to get the certificate from Let's Encrypt?
I want issuer to be Let's Encrypt Authority.

Comment: I think you could ask this question into [#service-fabric](https://traefik.slack.com/messages/C8J979UDA/) channel on [Traefik Slack](http://slack.traefik.io/)

Comment: I have posted question over there. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the certificate you have in key vault is the default cluster certificate for authenticating to the SF API.
The Service Fabric integration with LetsEncrypt is currently limited - I roughly documented the steps to setting it up here: https://github.com/jjcollinge/traefik-on-service-fabric/issues/21
Please note, we currently don't support clustering for the ACME certificates which can cause rate limiting issues as each Traefik instance requests its own cert.